# Visual Studio Regex Find and Replace function

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to find all `var.AppendLine("...");` and replace them with `Append("...\n");`

Been fooling around with regex's but don't seem to get anywhere. Anyone has a suggestion on what regular expression to use here?

`var` can be a variable name and I need to select the `...` for replace with `Append("$1\n");`

Comment: What regex did you tried? How does it behaves?

Comment: Well i googled a bit, but don't seem to have found anything that has results... Flying blind.

Comment: Regex.Replace(str, @"...", "...\n");

Comment: Its for the Visual Studio find and replace functionality

Comment: Sounds a bit dangerous... how confident are you there are no `");` WITHIN the text anywhere in the code?

Comment: Pretty confident, however i'll go by them line by line

Comment: I see that your question is effectively a duplicate of that I have just asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260224/how-do-i-insert-n-using-regex-replacement-in-msvs-2012-editor-and-net (or that is a duplicate of this). Your Q here did not come up in the list of similar questions above mine, but I noticed it later at the side under **Related**. As I comment there, I fear that the Search+Replace dialogue in the IDE converts `\n` to a new line before passing it to the RE engine.

Comment: P.S. In my question I suggest as a workaround replacing to get `\\n` and then replacing all those by `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you actually don't want to get rid of `var`:

Search: `<{[a-zA-Z0-9]+}.AppendLine\("{[^"]+}"\)`

Replace with: `\1.Append("\2\\n")`

Comment: Thanks Chris, almost there... I've used this now: (VS 2012): `([a-zA-Z0-9]+).AppendLine\("([^"]+)"\)` however, it selects sb.AppendLine.. and then b.AppendLine.. again...

Comment: @Ferdy: Fixed, need to match on word start

Comment: Adding the `<` breaks the regex for me. Has something to do with the tabs / spaces infront of it?

Comment: @Ferdy: Works fine for me in VS2010

Comment: Using VS 2012, got it working, however... It adds `\\n` at the end of the Append. When i use `\n` it adds a new line. Any way of adding `\n` litterally?

Comment: @Ferdy: Well `\\n` is supposed to do exactly that - as said the expression works fine for me on VS2010 for all examples I tested.

Comment: @ChrisWue: MSVS 2010 uses different RE syntax than 2013, which uses .NET REs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meand the regex in the "search& replace window of VS ? Then something like

```
<{[a-zA_Z]+\.}{AppendLine\("}{[^"]+}{"\)}
```

to replace with

```
\1Append("\3\\n")
```

(remove the \1 if you want to remove the "var." part, not clear in your question)

Comment: TIL that VS Replace uses curly braces, not brackets, for capture groups :-/

Comment: That looks like MSVS 2010 RE syntax, but the question is about MSVS 2012, which uses .NET RE syntax.