# How do I insert ‘\’+‘n’ using regex replacement in MSVS 2012+ editor (and .NET?)

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In the editor of Visual Studio 2013, which I understand is very similar to 2012 and ***allegedly*** uses .NET regexes, I cannot get the replacement string to insert a backslash and an ‘`n`’ — is that even possible?

I wish to insert ‘`\n`’ after the first ‘`"`’ on some (but not all) lines of a C programme, i.e. make the string literals start with a new line.
Obviously the expression to find is ‘`^([^"]*)"`’, and the replacement is … what? ‘`$1"`’ + *magic* + ‘`n`’, where *magic* is whatever inserts a backslash.
I am not trying to write .NET code to do this, but to do it interactively in the editor.

N.B. This question does ***not** apply to **MSVS 2010***, which has an older RE syntax.

#### Officially …

None of the [Substitutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) in the .NET reference is appropriate.

[Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecharacters.html) says ‘*You can't and needn't escape the backslash, exclamation point, or any other character except dollar, because they have no special meaning in .NET, JavaScript, VBScript, and PCRE2 replacement strings*’ — but MSVS RE Replace appears to treat ‘`\n`’ in the replacement as a new line!

[RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) (meant for .NET) says that ‘`^([^"]*)"`’→‘`$1"\n`’ transforms ‘`asdf"qwer`’→‘`asdf"\nqwer`’, which agrees with [Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecharacters.html).

#### Conclusion

My impression –and fear– is that the MSVS IDE itself transforms some C-style escapes such as ‘`\n`’, ‘`\r`’ and ‘`\t`’ in the edit dialogue before passing it to the RE engine, but leaves other backslashes unchanged. In particular, it does not provide a form such as ‘`\\`’ (or ‘`$\`’), as would be required to make inserting backslash possible. Given the documented RE engine behaviour, this is the only interpretation that makes sense to me; the conclusion is that you cannot insert a backslash that is interpreted as part of a C-style escape.

#### Experiments

I have tried various things for *magic*:

- These all yield themselves, even before ‘`n`’:

  - ‘`\\`’
  - ‘`\134`’
  - ‘`\x5cn`’
- ‘`\`’ before ‘`n`’ yields a new line
- ‘`$\`’ before ‘`n`’ yields ‘`$`’ + a new line

#### Workaround

I suspect I have to do a two step job, e.g.:

- ‘`^([^"]*)"`’→‘`$1"\\n`’
- ‘`^([^"]*"\\)\\`’→‘`$1`’

… that works, but is clumsier and more error-prone than a one-step solution.

Comment: Seems to me the escape is a special case in almost all scenarios. Otherwise, how would you replace a _thing_ with literal `\$1` ? I mean, what would that give you `$1` ??? Should it not allowed to be `\\\$1` ? If that's the case `\\n` should give a `\n` literal,

Comment: @sln: According to the documentation this is clear: `\$1` would give you a literal backslash followed by the last match of the first group. To insert literal `$1` you need a replacement string `$$1`, for literal `\$1` you need `\$$1`. I expect that to work in the IDE as well as the .NET run-time.

Comment: This is for the IDE right? I use vs2010 so can't test 2013. Do you have a link that describes the IDE usage on the replacement? If a literal really can't be replaced directly, its a sad day for M$ (to add to their other sad sh*t~). If it only allows literal `\\`, then `\\n` should be literal and not newline.

Comment: (try again) If it only allows literal `\ `, then `\n` should be literal and not newline.

Comment: Try the link to [Substitutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) in my question — but how long before that link rots, I wouldn’t know. Or do you want the IDE specifically? As I understand it, the IDE is meant to use .NET regexes, and should thus pass what you typed unchanged to it. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx for _Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio_.

Comment: Try this `Console.WriteLine( Regex.Replace("ABC", "...", "'\\n\n'") );` That's the way Dot-Net does it. There has to be a way to output the escape char _and_ ordinary whitespace linebreaks and such. Without that ability, its useless. Still, don't know about the IDE yet. I'll try to find out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to insert ‘\n’ after the first ‘"’

If one does not use regex but a standard text search and replace, it can be done. But one will need to do it by hand to skip the quote you don't want.

I would use NotePad++ for the regex `^\x22` (\x22 is the escape for quote, my habit when dealing with regex patterns and not having to literally escape the quote *for the C# compiler* such as `""` = `\x22`) and replacement `\\n` works and replaces the first quote of a line with a literal `\n` in Notepad++.

---

Note see other anomalies reported when dealing with special characters:

[Find and Replace dialog regex replacement can't escape a "$" symbol | Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773871/find-and-replace-dialog-regex-replacement-cant-escape-a-symbol)

---

In the older versions of Visual Studios with Macro capabilities, this could be accomplished.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I would agree that if one is doing a lot of RE editing then Notepad is a better way to go, but I think my two-step workaround less trouble for casual use when in MSVS anyway. The bug with escaping `$` has evidently been fixed, `$$` works fine for me. I would say it was the old RE syntax implementation which meant it worked in <= MSVS 2010, not the deeply lamented macros.

Comment: @PJTraill I wish I had a better answer for you for I do love regex and use it in the replace operations in Studio. I will send a frown in VS2015 on this issue to bring it to their attention. ... The result we see, seems like a trade off in VS and it appears they actively look for escaped characters and push them forward as there operational items; by design. But that is a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression appear to work.  The following code will display true:

```
var test = "asdf\"qwer";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(test, "^([^\"]*)", "$1\n");
Console.WriteLine(replaced[4] == '\n');
```

Perhaps you need a `"\r\n"` as @stephen.vakil suggests or something else is causing a problem in your code.

Comment: I am not trying to do the replacement **programmatically**, but interactively in the IDE.editor, which I fear was not clear enough in my question, which I have therefore edited. Moreover, your replacement string does not contain a backslash and an ‘n’ but a newline character. If I were doing it in code I would want `replaced[4] == '\\'  &&  replaced[5] == 'n'`!

Answer (score -1):

Try `$1\r\n` - it works for me in VS 2013.  That's assuming that you want a new line and not specifically `\n`

Comment: I am not trying to insert a new line, but a backslash and the letter n, so this does not help.

Comment: In that case a two-step seems fine and not error-prone if you use something other than \\n.  Replace with, for example, $1\PutANewLineHere and then replace PutANewLineHere with n.

Comment: Good point about reducing errors, even if “PutANewLineHere” seems a wee bit over the top.